# Why did my personal files and settings spontaneously disappear from Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. While I was working, almost all my personal folders were suddenly gone, both from my home folder and my desktop.

When I rebooted the computer, all my personal settings were gone too, like wallpaper, panels etc.

What happened? (I am not a complete newbie, I didn't just suddenly happen to erase my folders by accident.)

Comment: You may be right that it could have been disk problems. When I wanted to clone the hd now with the dd command, I got an error. Then I ran Gparted and to me it looked suspicious with 2 partitions overlapping.
I have posted another question on how to fix that with picture of how gparted shows my disk:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412152/is-this-an-overlapping-partition-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of /home/* as root to see if maybe access rights were revoked from your user account for some reason.

If your /home folder was on its own partition, it might have been unmounted, so check for mounts, e.g by executing "mount" in a shell.

Otherwise, a hard disk issue seems likely to me if you did not delete the contents yourself or ran some suspicious software.